# Injected JS not posting to the database at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been working around with this script for the past few days, as I want to save all the pots won at this website [csblitz.com](http://csblitz.com).

I can't seem to find the error.

I get no console errors, I targeted different things, the div where the last winner is shown and the message that pops up after the winner is chosen

```
//csblitz
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+'.'+'$2');
    }
    return val;
}
var counter = 0;
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) { 
    var elem =  $(event.target).find("div.round-last-winner.ng-binding.ng-scope");
    var text = elem.text().trim();
    if(text.length > 0){ 
        var firstIndex = text.lastIndexOf("$")+1; 
        text = text.substring(firstIndex, text.length);
        $.post("https://mywebsite.net/api/stats?sourceid=0&value="+text);
    }
});
```

Can't seem to find the issue, since I have other crawlers posting correctly to the database.

Comment: How are you executing this code?  A web-crawler isn't typically written using in-browser JS.

Comment: Paste it on the in-browser console. Eats a lot of CPU resources, but its doing it's job.

Comment: Also, you need to include at least a sample of the HTML elements you are targeting.